# Don't open new windows in full screen mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen, big-sur

This is most relevant when I'm working on multiple monitors. I will, for example, have a full-screen Microsoft Word app on one screen. I then press `Cmd+N` to open a new document. The new document opens a new MS Word window, as expected, but automatically puts the new window into full-screen mode. If the original window is not full-screen, then the new window is also not opened in full-screen mode. This occurs for other apps as well (e.g., Chrome).

Is there a way to stop macOS from opening new windows in full-screen mode? That is, I always want windows opened in non-full-screen mode (window-mode?), regardless of whether or not there are existing windows for that app in full-screen mode.

macOS version: 11.0.1

Comment: @MarcWilson When I originally asked this question back in 2020, this was the most recent OS. I'm currently on 14.3.1, and the behavior is the same.